# Simulate a pulse of specific power

Tags: matlab, discrete-signals

Suppose you produce a pulse `x` in discrete samples of duration `dt` each (e.g. in Matlab) according to a function.
I was given some notes in which it shows that if I want it to let it have a specific power I have to first normalize it by doing

```
energy = sum((x.^2).*dt) %first calculate the pulse energy
x = x./sqrt(energy) %normalize its energy to 1
```

then you calculate the target energy

```
power = 0 %target power in dBm
power = (10^(power/10))/1000 %target power in W
energy = power*len(x)*dt %target energy of the pulse
```

and finally you scale the pulse so that it has the target power

```
x = x .* sqrt(energy) %the pulse at the target power
```

My question is, how does that really work? Why dividing `x` by `sqrt(E)` normalize it to unit energy? And why multiplying the resulting normalized `x` by the new `sqrt(E)` brings it to the target power? Why not just divide by `E` for example? and then multiply by `E`? Does it have any relation to RMS values? And finally is it something that can be used in any arbitrary pulses, e.g. in sinusoids as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, for a signal $x[k]$, the energy is:
\begin{equation}
E=dt*\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}x^2[k]
\end{equation}

You want the energy to be one by dividing $x[k]$ through a value $a$, hence:
\begin{equation}
1=dt*\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}(\frac{x}{a})^2[k]
\end{equation}
which by multiplying with $a^2$ becomes
\begin{equation}
a^2=dt*\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}x^2[k]
\end{equation}
Comparing this to the first equation, it can be easily seen that $a^2=E$ and since $E$ is always positive, we can conclude $a=\sqrt{E}$. And that is why you divide by the square root of $E$.

From there it should be easy to see why multiplying this with $\sqrt{E'}$ makes a signal of energy $E'$.

Comment: excellent explanation, I am grateful!!!